# Create Validation in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have Report, and in my report i need return data between specific dates. For example `@EndDate` >= `@StartDate` + 1 month. I tried use `if` statement, but 0 result.

My if statement:

```
=IIf(Parameters!StartDate.Value<Parameters!EndDate.Value and Parameters!StartDate.Value<=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, Parameters!StartDate.Value), 'ERROR', DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, Parameters!StartDate.Value))
```

If user input not correct date, he must reinput dates.

Any advices will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While running your expression in report builder, I had an error :

> 'Textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error : [BC30201] Expression expected.

All I did was switching ' for " and, just like it should, the word ERROR appears. Here is the correct expression:

```
=IIf(Parameters!StartDate.Value<Parameters!EndDate.Value and Parameters!StartDate.Value<=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, Parameters!StartDate.Value), "ERROR", DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, Parameters!StartDate.Value))
```

Comment: In my report this code not working. I put it in the `General` tab->`value` expression. What i do wrong?

Comment: You need to put this code in the expression of a textbox.   Where are you writing this?

Comment: Did you suceeded? How?

Comment: I put condition to `TextBox` and it will display report if true, or report is invisible.

Comment: [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/1383c92d-9553-4a78-9d27-d2adf5cd3d9d/start-date-end-date-validation-in-report-builder-30) is more information.